# GCP cant disable compute engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service, google-api, google-compute-engine

To disable an API for a project:

1. Go to the Cloud Console API Dashboard page.
2. go to the API Dashboard page
3. Click Select to choose the Cloud project.
4. Next to the API you want to disable, click Disable.

but... error...

```
[Could not turn off service, as it still has resources in use.] with failed services [compute.googleapis.com]
```

Answer (score 3):

Compute API, is much more than compute instance. Look at the gcloud command (perform a `gcloud compute` then 2 times TAB for autocomplete proposal)

```
guillaume_blaquiere@cloudshell:~$ gcloud compute
accelerator-types         disk-types                instance-templates        regions                   snapshots                 target-pools
addresses                 external-vpn-gateways     interconnects             reservations              sole-tenancy              target-ssl-proxies
backend-buckets           firewall-rules            machine-types             reset-windows-password    ssh                       target-tcp-proxies
backend-services          forwarding-rules          network-endpoint-groups   resource-policies         ssl-certificates          target-vpn-gateways
commitments               health-checks             networks                  routers                   ssl-policies              tpus
config-ssh                http-health-checks        operations                routes                    start-iap-tunnel          url-maps
connect-to-serial-port    https-health-checks       os-config                 scp                       target-grpc-proxies       vpn-gateways
copy-files                images                    os-login                  security-policies         target-http-proxies       vpn-tunnels
diagnose                  instance-groups           packet-mirrorings         shared-vpc                target-https-proxies      zones
disks                     instances                 project-info              sign-url                  target-instances
```

Have a check on the most important, such as disks, images, snapshots, templates, MIG, VPN, shared VPC, router, load balancer and VPN.

Comment: <gcloud compute resource-policies list>
Listed 0 items.

[Could not turn off service, as it still has resources in use.]
HELP ME~~~

Comment: Try this command `gcloud asset search-all-resources --query=//compute.googleapis.com*`

Answer (score 0):

Please double confirm if you still have a GCE instance running, if so please stop the instance first.