# Unable to disable Compute Engine and Notebooks API on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have been trying to disable the Compute Engine API and Notebook API, but have no luck. Here’s what I have tried so far:

- via the API services
- via gcloud commands

  ```bash
  gcloud services disable compute.googleapis.com --force
  ```

Neither work. I got the attached error when I tried using the API service: [image]

All the resources have been deleted both in the Compute Engine and Notebooks, so I am not sure why it is still holding it up.

Anyone experienced this before?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GCP cant disable compute engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63761135/gcp-cant-disable-compute-engine)

Answer (score 0):

I've found some interesting information related to your issue. It has to do with permissions and dependent services.

Regarding permissions, I think that's not the issue, as no IAM error is shown. However, it's worth double checking you have enough permissions for using Service Usage [here](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/access-control).

Next, checking the [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/enable-disable#disabling), I noticed the blue note stating the following:

> In v1 of the API, if you attempt to disable a service that other enabled services depend on, the call will fail. The API call to disable the service will result in an error message

Therefore, my current hypothesis is that there are other dependent services that prevent the API from being disabled.

As I saw that you are using the `--force` command, let's get straight to the point. You can set the `disable_dependent_services` parameter on the [services.disable request](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/reference/rest/v1/services/disable) to `true`.

Hope that helped!

Comment: I tried the following
gcloud services disable notebooks.googleapis.com disable_dependent_services=true check_if_service_has_usage=SKIP --force

That still didnt work. Any suggestions?

Comment: `disable_dependent_services=true` and `check_if_service_has_usage=SKIP` are parameters intended to be used on an API call. If you check the gcloud services [reference](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/services/disable) you'll see that these are not valid parameters.